# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) when runModalForWindow

Tags: objective-c, macos, exc-bad-access

I have a window and a window controller which opens when the user clicks a button.
Sometimes I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0).

```
0x7fff6f2a59e0:  movq   (%rax), %rdi
```

Here is the code:

```
    ChooseProceduresWindowController *chooseProceduresWindowController = [[ChooseProceduresWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ChooseProceduresWindow"];
    [NSApp runModalForWindow:[chooseProceduresWindowController window]];
```

The error appears then runModalForWindow: is called.
I don't get this error every time, but I couldn't find a pattern.

Thanks

Comment: Are both windows guaranteed to be owned (`strongly`) for the entire duration of the modal action? Inadvertent early releases by ARC are often the cause of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exceptions, particularly at `0x0`.

Answer (score 3):

the best way to debug `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors is to use `NSZombies`.

Check out this video for an explanation :

http://youtu.be/LQtPr8bkB3g

`NSZombie` keeps all your objects in memory when you are trying to release an object that has already been released, so you get closer to finding your bug. As @Mark H said, it is a memory management issue.

Also you could put an `NSLog` in your dealloc method to have a better idea of what is getting deallocated when at runtime.

Comment: Sometimes an object in the middle of being deallocated throws a "does not respond to selector" exception. And sometimes EXC_BAD_ACCESS is due to reading outside of the bounds of an array (seg fault), if I'm not wrong... But `NSZombies` is a good measure to start.

Answer (score 1):

That error will be thrown when the object doesn't exist in memory. I'd start looking for memory management issues. The first would be to make sure you are releasing the ChooseProceduresWindowController after using it.

Comment: I get the error before releasing, when I try to open it in modal.

Comment: Do you open it multiple times and does it ever error out on the first try?

Comment: Yes, I open it multiple times, and No, I didn't get the error on the first try.

Comment: What does the code look like for releasing the allocated memory? Does it always get called?

Comment: [chooseProceduresWindowController release]; - just after the runForModal:

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but it seems like you are releasing the memory immediately after allocating it. Release the memory when you are done with the modal window.

Comment: @MarkH: `runModalForWindow:` blocks until the modal event loop has been stopped or aborted (hopefully by the questioner's code in response to an action).

Comment: I ran into this error when I tried releasing an alertView twice. (Still a noob at Objective-C)